# Can a command be defined to have key=value in it?

Tags: macros, key-value

I am learning about making LaTeX commands. I thought that they were just macro, and the command is replaced literally by its definition. But the following example does not work and I wanted to ask if it could be made to work and, more important, why it does not work.

Given this

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{whatever}  %standard
\end{document}
```

I wanted to build the `width=0.8\textwidth` using my own command. This works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \newcommand{\X}[1]{#1\textwidth}  %works
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=\X{0.8}]{whatever} %newcommand
\end{document}
```

But when changing the whole thing to be command, like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \newcommand{\Y}[1]{width=#1\textwidth} %does not work
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[\Y{0.8}]{whatever}
\end{document}
```

Latex gave the following error:

```
 Missing \endcsname inserted. \includegraphics[\Y{0.8}]{whatever}
```

So my whole thinking that commands are just blind macro replacements (like `#define` in C) was wrong, or maybe Latex is trying to evaluate things inside the `\newcommand` and that is why it complained?

Is there a way to make the last example above work as shown?

TL 2015

Comment: It is to do with... er... does the term 'expansion' mean much to you? If your heart isn't sinking, you have a whole world of woe yet to discover....

Comment: @cfr I do not know what "expansion" exactly mean in Latex world. Is it like Latex is trying to evaluate the command before it is applied to the `\includegraphics` part? something like this may be. I do not know, that is why I am asking.

Comment: It sees `width=stuff` as a single unit. So it complains that it doesn't know that key because the key it knows is `width` and not `width=stuff`. Expanding a macro within an argument to another command is, in general, tricky. In this case, the way that it gets parsed is that it tries to make the whole spec into a key which `\includegraphics` knows.... But I am not a good person to be commenting on this at all. It is well beyond my ken.

Comment: to extend @cfr's comment, you may do `\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\Y{0.8}]{whatever}` to get it to work

Comment: As @ThomasWeise's comment shows, you're probably better off doing something like `\newcommand{\Y}[2][1]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}}` (then `\Y[0.5]{whatever` and `\Y{whatever}`) if you're really keen on saving some typing and will have many images that must be set at different widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to expand the optional argument in order for `\Y{<x>}` to appropriately be seen as `width=<x>\textwidth`. Here are a number of ways to achieve this:

#### First approach:

An indirect way of expanding the optional argument (and possibly the mandatory one, depending on the usage).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Y}[1]{width=#1\textwidth}
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\expandafter\oldincludegraphics\expandafter}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[\Y{0.1},height=50pt]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

#### Second approach

A more direct approach by expanding only the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,letltxmacro}
\newcommand{\Y}[1]{width=#1\textwidth}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\oldincludegraphics\expandafter[#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[\Y{0.1},height=50pt]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

#### Third approach

A complete expansion of the macros argument(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,letltxmacro}
\newcommand{\Y}[1]{width=#1\textwidth}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup%
    \noexpand\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}\x}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[\Y{0.1},height=50pt]{example-image}
\end{document}
```