# Errors when using conditionals in document class optional argument

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, debugging

I have encountered a strange interaction between the optional parameters on `\documentclass` and `\if` statements.
For some reason, the code compiles if there is an `\else` statement, even if it has no content:

```
\newif\ifdraftversion \draftversionfalse
\newif\iffullversion  \fullversionfalse

\documentclass[
  \iffullversion  twoside,  \fi %works if the \fi here are
  \ifdraftversion draft,    \fi % \else\fi instead
  11pt
]{article}

\begin{document}
This is a MWE, although it generates an extra warning that would
disappear if I added substantially more content to the document
\end{document}
```

While this work-around is not particularly onerous, I have not been able to isolate the actual bug involved, or work out what I have misunderstood. Is there some reason why my intuition is leading me to use invalid syntax, and if so where/what/why?

Comment: You should first ask whether this is supported syntax. No, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to get at with "or work out what I have misunderstood". I will update that sentence to be more clear, although following http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/should-i-change-a-question-title-once-i-know-the-answer I don't think I should change the title

Comment: Related: [Can a command be defined to have key=value in it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256778/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\documentclass` command does some bookkeeping, then calls

```
\@fileswithoptions\@clsextension
```

At this point the options and the argument haven't yet been looked at. The macro `\@fileswithoptions` absorbs its argument and then looks whether `[` follows. After this decision, it executes

```
\@fileswith@ptions\@clsextension[<options>]{article}
```

which looks for a further optional argument; in the end we arrive at

```
\@fileswith@pti@ns\@clsextension[<options>]{article}[]
```

because you don't specify the trailing optional argument. This macro does

```
\xdef\@classoptionslist{\zap@space<options> \@empty}
```

so we should ask what happens if we do it with your options. After tokenization, we get

```
\zap@space \iffullversion twoside, \fi\ifdraftversion draft, \fi 11pt \@empty
```

The definition of `\zap@space` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 7764:
\def\zap@space#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\zap@space\fi
  #2}
```

For the first call, `#1` is empty, so we get

```
\zap@space\iffullversion twoside, \fi\ifdraftversion draft, \fi 11pt \@empty
```

This leaves `\iffulversion twoside,` in the input stream and then does

```
\ifx\fi\ifdraftversion draft, \fi 11pt \@empty
```

Can you see what goes wrong? The conditional compares `\fi` with `\ifdraftversion` and removes them.

If you use `\else\fi`, then the comparison is between these two; you could use `\relax\fi` or `\whateverevenundefined\fi`.

At this point the unbalanced `\fi` is clear. In your application the error is discovered later, but this should be enough to explain that conditionals in the class options are to be avoided.

This works, by the way:

```
\newif\ifdraftversion \draftversionfalse
\newif\iffullversion  \fullversionfalse
\def\safetybelt{\empty}

\documentclass[%
  \safetybelt\iffullversion  twoside,\fi
  \safetybelt\ifdraftversion draft,\fi
  11pt
]{article}
```

Comment: I can indeed. It appears from what you've said that I would be fine building the parameter string within an initial \edef then chucking that down the parameter string.

Comment: @figlesquidge Yes, that's a more viable option

Answer (score 2):

The "workaround" using `\else\fi` only *seems* to work. Your options are split on the commas, so you have the options `\iffullversion  twoside`, `\fi\ifdraftversion draft`, and `\fi 11pt`.

The following code *seems* to work as expected (only verified by experiment):

```
\documentclass[
  \iffullversion  twoside\fi, %works if the \fi here are
  \ifdraftversion draft\fi, % \else\fi instead
  11pt
]{article}
```

Comment: Interestingly (or so I think) your version doesn't work on my compiler (pdfTex 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14).  Thanks for answering my core question. I would be interested in a more involved answer or link to trusted source that outlined why this is not correct if you know of one?

Comment: @figlesquidge The trusted source is `latex.ltx` or `latex.dtx`, if you want to know precisely why it fails, or why some version works in certain situations. As egreg mentioned, your extension is not documented and not officially supported, so you can just try (and must expect that if fails any time).